# uiwebview not loading images from xml

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xml, uiwebview

I have problems which I don't know how to solve it I hope someone could help me.

I have **MasterViewController**, who is showing news from xml and **DetailViewController** is showing details from selected topic in MVC and showing in `UIWebView`. First problem is images is not loaded from xml in `UIWebView`, and second problem is how to made that links below the text is showing in another uiWebView when I press it.

[image: description from xml in UiWebView]

My code is:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"description"];
    NSString *htmlStrippedString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</?[a-z]+>" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
    htmlStrippedString = [htmlStrippedString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    DetailViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    dvc.myString = htmlStrippedString;
  }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [webView loadHTMLString:myString baseURL:nil];
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the URL for the image in the xml?

Comment: this is a piece of my xml 
<![CDATA[
<img align="left" hspace="10" width="80" height="80" alt="AVDIO: Po desetih letih Slovenec spet na stopničkah na novoletni turneji" src="/s/c/images.24ur.com/media/images/210/mar2013/80x80/61180414.jpg" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web view does not have the correct path for the image, as the src="" is wrong in the  tag:

> src="/s/c/images.24ur.com/media/images/210/mar2013/80x80/61180414.jpg"

You need to change the way that the image path manifests itself as HTML. Specifically, you need to give the HTML page the correct path so it can pull the image. For example, something like this:

> src="HTTP://YOURSITE.COM/s/c/images.24ur.com/media/images/210/mar2013/80x80/61180414.jpg"

I hope this helps!

Comment: Problem is this is what i get from xml, but thank you both, i will try what you suggest.

Comment: No problem. You may have to pull this XML node separately, and add the URL to the string and store it as a variable. For example, in PHP: **$xml_url = $xml_object-> URL;** then you would add the URL to the beginning of the variable: **$xml_url= "HTTP://YOURSITE.COM/".$xml_url;** I hope this helps!

Comment: yes Musser, this is exactly what i need, but i don't have much knowledge to do that in Obj.c.  I google it but no lucky. Does exitst some tutorial with that topic? Thank you for helping all you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You img src file is calling out to

```
/s/c/images.24ur.com/media/images/210/mar2013/80x80/61180414.jpg
```

which makes no sense when in a `UIWebView`. Relative links like this depend on the browsers ability to prepend the server, but UIWebView is not that smart. You need to prepend an `http://whatever.server.the.image.lives.at.com` to the `src` so that the web view is requesting a valid URL:

```
http://whatever.server.the.image.lives.at.com/s/c/images.24ur.com/media/images/210/mar2013/80x80/61180414.jpg
```